# How to use Node.js, Express, and Socket.io in a PHP file being served by Apache?

Tags: php, node.js, apache, express, socket.io

I am working on a project that was written in PHP and being served on an Apache server. I have been asked to integrate Socket.io live chat functionality into a page that was written in PHP and served by Apache. To do this, I've been writing a Node.js application with Express. But I can't figure out a way to integrate my Express app into the PHP page.

I have googled this for several hours and found many tutorials about running Node.js and Apache on the same server but different ports, but as I understand it, that strategy would limit me to serving different *pages* or different files. What I need is to be able to use the Socket.io livechat function on the PHP page.

I thought maybe I could use an iframe integrated into the PHP page to display the livechat window itself, but I also need to display new chat request notifications on the PHP page and give the user the ability to click different tabs to switch between chat windows. I thought I could probably have the tab clicks handled by writing a REST API on the Node.js end and letting the PHP page make calls to that. But I'm not sure how I would have the PHP page display new chat request notifications if I can't have Express and Apache handling the same page.

So my question is basically how to:
1) Configure things so one PHP page can be accessed and manipulated by both the PHP side and the Node.js/Express side of things, or
2) Route Socket.io events from the Node.js/Express side into the PHP side so that they can be handled on that end.

Context: I know minimal, minimal PHP--that's being handled by my colleagues, and my role is the JavaScript and Node.js stuff--so please keep that in mind.

Comment: The fact that you have PHP is largely irrelevant. You can code socket connection code in client-side and server-side javascript.

Comment: @apokryfos, that's what I've been doing. But when I try to connect the JavaScript/Node stuff to the PHP page that's being served by Apache, Node (and more importantly, Socket.io) has no idea about the page's existence. Is there a way for Socket.io on my Node side to "hear" a user connect to the existing PHP page and understand that as a Socket.io connection event? This is where I'm getting stuck.

Comment: Write client-side JavaScript which on page load connects to wherever Socket.io is listening. In jQuery you could probably do something like `$(function () { var connection = io('ws://<host or ip address>:<port number>') })` or something like this. Then you can set event listeners on that connection object.

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution I finally stumbled on not two minutes ago too. I was failing to specify a URL & port for my socket to listen to, but now that I set it to listen to the right URL & port, it's working fine!

For anyone with a similar question:
In my client-side JavaScript, I had: ``var socket = io();`` and it worked when I changed it to ``var socket = io('http://localhost:3000);`` (the port my server is running on).

Comment: And, using that different port means that your socket.io connection now has nothing to do with either Apache or PHP at all.  You're connecting directly from the web page to your node.js server.